# Remove Cell Does not work after Loading mxGraph using Decode XML

Tags: mxgraph

I keep my mxModel saved in DataBase.
Once a model is saved , the mxModel xml is saved in Database.
So when the user wants to edit that model, I retrieve the model and decode it using the following code

```
var xmlDocument = mxUtils.parseXml(mxModel);
var decoder = new mxCodec(xmlDocument);
                    
var node = xmlDocument.documentElement;
decoder.decode(node, graph.getModel());
let elt = xmlDocument.documentElement.firstChild;
```

Beyond this, I have options in the graph to edit the graph further. Like Add,Copy, Delete etc .
All the Add Operations are working fine, but the Operations which is are trying to remove cells its not getting reflected in the graph realtime.

So for example for Delete operation, I have the following code bounded under beginUpdate() and endupdate()

```
graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
graph.removeCellsFromParent([selectedCell]);
graph.getModel().remove(e[0]);
graph.getModel().remove(selectedCell);
graph.getModel().endUpdate();
```

With this operation, the delete is happening but its not reflected in the screen. I have arrived to this conclusion because when I save the Model and reload it, the deleted cell is no longer there.

I need to show the delete in real time. Can you please show some direction for the same.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue did you find any answer please let me know

Answer (score 0):

we have demo with [removeCells](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/visibility.html)
In code call `graph.removeCells()`
You can see [here](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/7af5a44c5b2d8a4d0fc56d3eebc964c3ca8b82de/javascript/examples/visibility.html#L104).

If it will not help you, please create an online demo(codePen, etc) with trouble and write here.

Comment: As I mentioned the graph.removeCells() only works when the cell is created using graph.insertvertex() but in my case I am loading it via codec decoder, in which case it fails to show the changes once I perform graph.removeCells().

Answer (score 0):

graph.model.cells is an object and its cells (vertices and edges) are properties of the object.

```
console.log(graph.getModel());
```

[image: graph.model.cells items]

When you remove a cell, it's visually removed from mxGraph container but remain as object property, and when you update mxModel in database, nothing changed.

In my case,after graph.getModel().removeCells([cells]); I deleted property of removed cell from graph.Model.cells manually.

```
graph.removeCells([cell]);
let cellKey = Object.keys(graph.model.cells).find(
  (key) => graph.model.cells[key]["id"] === cell["id"]
);

console.log(cellKey);

delete graph.model.cells[cellKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do both of the following

```
graph.model.remove(cell);
graph.removeStateForCell(cell);
```

> removeStateForCell: Removes all cached information for the given cell and its descendants